# How do I configure my "mv" command to include "-i" option even when I forgot it?

Tags: linux

I want to configure my mv command to implicitly include "-i" by default.

Sometimes I forgot to use it and mess up my files...

Comment: I'd argue that you shouldn't do that.  If you do, you will condition yourself to expect a safety-net.  When you use an environment that doesn't have that alias (including using your current system as a different user), you may well make mistakes that you wouldn't make without that conditioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding another answer to include unaliasing option, you need to add to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` based on your login shell for a permanent alias.

```
alias mv="mv -i"
```

Then you can source it to take effect on the current login

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Sometimes, if you want to disable the behavior temporarily, you can do it by

```
\mv oldfile newfile
```

Answer (score 5):

In your `.bashrc` or similar settings, add `alias mv="mv -i"`. Then start a new shell.

Answer (score 1):

Temporal way to do it:

```
alias mv='mv -i'
```

or Permanent way:
What C-Otto wrote